# iCloud Calendar sync error 400 on OS X 10.10.2

Tags: macos, icloud, calendar

I've been using Calendar with iCloud for a long while without any problems. Now, I have a permanent error displayed in Calendar:

> The request for account “iCloud” failed.
>
> The server responded with “400” to operation CalDAVAddSubscriptionCalendarQueueableOperation

I've searched around online and have tried all of the proposed solutions, but none of them seem to fix the problem. What should I try next?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you've tried so far...

Comment: 400 is the missing of correct Internet address. Check your settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try this to Reset your iCal operations.

Back up calendars and Disable calendars in iCloud Preferences  :

Go to:

- ~/Library/Calendars
- /Library/Preferences/com.apple.CalendarAgent
- /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist

Move all to the desktop.

Restart.

Comment: how do you back up calendars and how do you disable them ?

Comment: So after you move the files to the desktop and restart then what? Do I delete the file from the desktop, copy and past back into ical, trash the folder??????Dont want extra files living on my desktop

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. This is a server error that you need to wait for Apple to fix (easily confirmed by trying to access your calendar from icloud.com or another device). Following this instructions will wipe out your calendar.

Comment: Whenever you get an error like this, try first checking [iCloud status](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/).

Answer (score 0):

I am running Yosemite 10.10.5 to make this happen I had to first Show All Hidden files by:

1) Open Terminal and type the command:
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

2) Hit Return

3) Mouse over the Finder icon, hold option, right click and relaunch finder

4) Open a new Finder window and navigate to:
/Users/username/Library/Preferences/

5) Locate the two files: com.apple.iCal.plist, com.apple.CalendarAgent

6) Move them to the desktop and restart

This is different than the instructions above in that the location of the folders you're looking for may or may not be in the same place depending on which specific version of OS X you're running. This is the only place I was able to find the files.